# PARSE JS - query of username is not returning results

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Here is my JS code:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("username", "mgunnels123");
    query.find({
                success: function(preferences) {
                        console.log(preferences);
               }
    });
```

This username does exist in my parse DB. Please see the screenshot below:
[image]

The console response returns a blank array: [ ]

I've been trying everything that I can, however, I can't seem to get a different result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: console the `Parse.User`

Comment: console.log(Parse.User) returns: function (){a.apply(this,arguments)}

Comment: remove this line `query.equalTo("username", "mgunnels123");` and try it. do you get all user result?

Comment: INTERESTING...it is only returning the "logged" in user results. Any idea how to overcome this issue?